# curl http code with redirections

Tags: php, curl

I'm new with curl and I can't find my answer.
I want to get the http status of a page, so I'm using

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

But this does not work if there is a redirection (for example a 301 that redirect to another page, it will give me a 200 answer) because curlinfo_http_code gives the **Last** received HTTP code

Any idea how I can get the first received http code ?
 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure curl with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = 0

Answer (score 0):

The way I am accomplishing this is by having PHP consult an INI file with the different return codes and replacing them with something human readable

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); // create cURL handle (ch)
if (!$ch) {
    die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
}
// set some cURL options
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://mail.yahoo.com");
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         1);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);

// execute
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

if (empty($ret)) {
    // some kind of an error happened
    die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
} else {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler

    if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
            die("No HTTP code was returned"); 
    } else {
        // load the HTTP codes
        $http_codes = parse_ini_file("HTMLCodes.ini");

        // echo results
        echo "The server responded: <br />";
        echo $http_codes[$info['http_code']];
    }

}
?> 

example of the ini file with return codes

[Informational 1xx]
100="Continue"
101="Switching Protocols"

[Successful 2xx]
200="OK"
201="Created"
202="Accepted"
203="Non-Authoritative Information"
204="No Content"
205="Reset Content"
206="Partial Content"

[Redirection 3xx]
300="Multiple Choices"
301="Moved Permanently"
302="Found"
303="See Other"
304="Not Modified"
305="Use Proxy"
306="(Unused)"
307="Temporary Redirect"
```